# Spring3 ModelAttribute from jsp request params

Tags: spring, modelattribute

Is it possible to grab various form components and turn them into their corresponding DAO objects?  I'm trying to avoid creating a custom Bean (which encapsulates all fields) for each Form.

Ex:

```
<form action="/add">
  <input name="foo" id="foo" value="29"/>
  <input name="bar" id="bar" value="63"/>
</form>


public void add(@ModelAttribute("foo") Foo myFoo, @ModelAttribute("bar") Bar myBar)
```

Currently, I'd have to use the HttpRequest, extract the values (29,63), and use them as primary keys to look up the correct database objects.  I didn't know if there was a quick way to auto-wire this using ModelAttribute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use @RequestParam

```
public void add(@RequestParam("foo") Foo myFoo, @RequestParam("bar") Bar myBar) {
}
```

Comment: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'Foo'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [Foo]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: This works out of the box with primitive types. For custom Classes, you need to use a custom binder with the @InitBinder annotation see example http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s11.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to address if both Foo and Bar are being passed as Strings.  It seems like the best way to go is to take in an int as a requestparam and use a dao service to pull up the dao object

Comment: in an HTTP request the params are always sent as String. If you use a custom object then you need to use a binder that tells spring how to convert a string to your object